# how to debug javascript in django templates with vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

what is the proper setting for debugging the java-script in django templates with chrome/firefox extension alongside django debug?

is it possible to debug django and java-script in templates simultaneously?
debug django in vscode and java-script in browser

Comment: Im tring to find a solution to this same problem...have solved it yet? Do you mind sharing :)?

Comment: I've done this before.  Forgot how.  If I find something I'll post here.

Comment: @AndyParzyszek solved, it see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this again after an hour of tinkering.

[image: Screenshot of setup]

As you can see in the setup, I put a breakpoint inside some JS ran by index.html.   This web app https://q.uiver.app normally, I've locally hosted the files of (it's a JS + html app).  I simply added as a submodule my forked varkor/quiver source code.  I then  created a new launch configuration and used all defaults except I changed the port to 8000, which is the Django default debug port.  So I have Wingware running in the background.  That's running the Django site / server.  I then click launch / run on VS code and the Django site loads and as you can see, as long as you set your webRoot correctly (the default) then things will work.  But that assumes you opened the Django project root as a workspace folder in VS.

Anyway, your Django root = JS launch config webRoot always.  Then it will work.
Otherwise, JS breakpoints will not work..

This is just for debugging Javascript.  There's other tutorials out there for debugging Python in VSCode.  But like I said I use Wingware IDE, so... why would I want to do that?

Comment: My quiver copy is hosted in DjangoRoot/static/quiver/... and I include DjangoRoot/static/quiver/src/index.html into a Django template using an iframe.   There's no difference though if you had your JS called in / from a Django template.  But it's good to know that it even works, through an iframe!!!